# how to update a Google calendar event from asp application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, api

i want to insert a primary key of event to Google calendar and then retrieve it after EventQuery call to update that event

i didn't find any property in Evententry class to assign primary key and later to retrieve for  updating that event.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using ExtendedProperty using the approach below

```
1.Assign an ID (same as you set in your DB) to each event you add through
  ExtendedProperty . 
2.When updating / deleting you pass the ID and use Query to fetch it for you
3.If the event is found you can delete / update the specific event

Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry Entry = new Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry();

//create the ExtendedProperty and add the EventID in the new event object, 
//so it can be deleted / updated later
ExtendedProperty oExtendedProperty = new ExtendedProperty();
oExtendedProperty.Name = "EventID";
oExtendedProperty.Value = GoogleAppointmentObj.EventID;
Entry.ExtensionElements.Add(oExtendedProperty);

string ThisFeedUri = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" + CalendarID 
+ "/private/full";
Uri postUri = new Uri(ThisFeedUri);

//create an event query object and attach the EventID to it in Extraparameters
EventQuery Query = new EventQuery(ThisFeedUri);
Query.ExtraParameters = "extq=[EventID:" + GoogleAppointmentObj.EventID + "]";
Query.Uri = postUri;

//Find the event with the specific ID
EventFeed calFeed = CalService.Query(Query);

//if search contains result then delete
if (calFeed != null && calFeed.Entries.Count > 0)
{
   foreach (EventEntry SearchedEntry in calFeed.Entries)
   {
      SearchedEntry.Delete();
      //To update comment the code above and uncomment the code below 
      //CalService.Update(SearchedEntry);
      break;
   }
}
else
{
    InsertedEntry = CalService.Insert(postUri, Entry);
}
```